# How to send output to stderr?

Tags: rust, stdio

One uses this to send output to stdout:

```
println!("some output")
```

I think there is no corresponding macro to do the same for stderr.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

## After Rust 1.19

As of Rust 1.19, you can use the [`eprint`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.eprint.html) and [`eprintln`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.eprintln.html) macros:

```
fn main() {
    eprintln!("This is going to standard error!, {}", "awesome");
}
```

This was originally proposed in [RFC 1896](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1869-eprintln.md).

## Before Rust 1.19

You can see the [implementation of `println!`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.7.0/src/libstd/macros.rs#L118-L121) to dive into exactly how it works, but it was a bit overwhelming when I first read it.

You can format stuff to stderr using similar macros though:

```
use std::io::Write;

let name = "world";
writeln!(&mut std::io::stderr(), "Hello {}!", name);
```

This will give you a `unused result which must be used` warning though, as printing to IO *can fail* (this is not something we usually think about when printing!). We can see that the existing methods [simply panic](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.7.0/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs#L625-L627) in this case, so we can update our code to do the same:

```
use std::io::Write;

let name = "world";
let r = writeln!(&mut std::io::stderr(), "Hello {}!", name);
r.expect("failed printing to stderr");
```

This is a bit much, so let's wrap it back in a macro:

```
use std::io::Write;

macro_rules! println_stderr(
    ($($arg:tt)*) => { {
        let r = writeln!(&mut ::std::io::stderr(), $($arg)*);
        r.expect("failed printing to stderr");
    } }
);

fn main() {
    let name = "world";
    println_stderr!("Hello {}!", name)
}
```

Comment: So, it's `println_stderr!("Hello {}!", name)` vs. `writeln!(&mut std::stdio::stderr(), "Hello {}!", name)`, both which do pretty much the same thing?

Comment: They do the same thing, but the macro handles the fail case (the return value) without all the cruft. Without it, you get a warning.

Comment: You could also do `writeln!(...).unwrap();` to handle possible failure in the simplest way.

Answer (score 21):

[`print!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.print!.html) and [`println!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.println!.html) are convenience methods for writing to standard output. There are other macros with the same formatting features available for different tasks:

- [`write!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.write!.html) and [`writeln!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.writeln!.html) to write a formatted string to a `&mut Writer`
- [`format!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format!.html) to just generate a formatted `String`

To write to the standard error stream, you can use e.g. `writeln!` like this:

```
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut stderr = std::io::stderr();
    writeln!(&mut stderr, "Error!").unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's done so:

```
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    std::io::stderr().write(b"some output\n");
}
```

You can test it by sending the program output to `/dev/null` to ensure it works (I ignore the warning):

```
$ rustc foo.rs && ./foo > /dev/null
foo.rs:4:5: 4:42 warning: unused result which must be used, #[warn(unused_must_use)] on by default
foo.rs:4     io::stderr().write(b"some output\n");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
some output
```

Similarly, one can do the following for stdout:

```
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    std::io::stdout().write(b"some output\n");
}
```

I think this means `println!` is just a convenience: it's shorter and it also allows some formatting. As an example of the latter, the following displays `0x400`:

```
println!("0x{:x}", 1024u)
```

Answer (score 3):

While not answering the precise question, maybe it’s of interest that there’s a `log` crate which specifies an interface for leveled logging that other crates (e.g. `env_logger`) can fulfill.

The output of such logging will be sent to `stderr`, and there are additional benefits for users, such as specifying the log level.

This is how using such a logger could look like:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
extern crate env_logger;

fn main() {
    env_logger::init().unwrap();
    error!("this is printed by default");
}
```

(Example adapted from http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/env_logger/index.html#example)

Answer (score 0):

#### Goal

```
stderr!("Code {}: Danger, Will Robinson!  Danger!", 42);
```

#### Notes

The other answers generate an unused import warning with the latest nightly, so here's a modern macro that Just Works TM.

#### Code

```
macro_rules! stderr {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => (
        use std::io::Write;
        match writeln!(&mut ::std::io::stderr(), $($arg)* ) {
            Ok(_) => {},
            Err(x) => panic!("Unable to write to stderr (file handle closed?): {}", x),
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: My answer has no warnings on the nightly on the [Rust Playground nightly](http://is.gd/XEFTKk). What are you seeing?

Comment: This solution doesn't work: error: imports are not allowed after non-item statements

Comment: This happens for me if you use the macro in a block after another statement. If you wrap the inner bit with the `use` and `match` in another block, it works for me. So `($($arg:tt)*) => ({ use ... })`