# Rust: how to make a formatted print to stderr?

Tags: printing, rust, stderr

I'm trying to print a formatted string to `stderr` in Rust (curious newbie here!), but it looks like an easy convenience macro (such as `print!/println!` for `stdout`) isn't provided in the standard library.

In C, one could just do it like this:

```
fprintf(stderr, "format_string", args ...);
```

I've successfully printed string *literals* to `stderr` with

```
let stderr = std::io::stderr();
writeln!(&mut stderr, "literal");
```

The next thing that came into mind was to do a `format!` first, and then use `writeln!`, mut that fails to compile with `error: expected a literal`. On the other hand, `stderr.write()` expects `&[u8]`, so using `String::bytes().collect()` doesn't really work either..

What are the correct solutions to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [answer of the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27590832/2408867). Since Rust 1.19, you can use the `eprintln!` macro.

Comment: lol! :D ok, thanks. /fail