# How to convert a Rust integer type to its string representation without allocating a String?

Tags: io, rust, type-conversion

I have a `count: u32` that I need to push through a TCP stream as its ASCII byte representation. For example if the value is 42, I want to write the bytes `[52, 50]` (ASCII for "42") to the stream.

I can do this by first creating a `String` with:

```rust
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn write_number<T: Write>(writer: &mut T, num: u32) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
    let num_as_str: String = num.to_string();
    let num_as_bytes = num_as_str.as_bytes();
    writer.write(num_as_bytes)
}
```

Is this is a wasteful way of doing this? I don't feel that allocating a `String` should be necessary for this task. Is there a more efficient way to implement `write_number`? I've tried going through `str`, but `str` does not implement `From<u32>`.

Comment: Note that the linked question does *more* than you asked; all you need to know about to avoid allocating a `String` is the `write!` macro (`writeln!` also exists). Also see [How can I append a formatted string to an existing String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28333612/3650362) (which applies to more than just `String`s) and [How to send output to stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27588416/3650362).

Comment: Based on that answer, it appears I can simply do `write!(writer, "{}", num)`. I now understand why the `Display` trait works the way it does. Thanks!